# Formatting XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've been trying to find a similar answered question but I haven't had any luck.

I basically need to read some data off a text file and then marshal it to XML. Normal formatting though, creates

```
<title></title>
```

fields etc. while what I want is every field to have this format:

```
<field name="title"></field>.
```

"title" here is just a placeholder, what I want is for the name attribute to have the variable name which it is bound, so

```
<title>
```

becomes

```
<field name="title">
```

,

```
<author>
```

becomes

```
<field name="author"> etc.
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the annotations that I'm not getting.

My document class has a simple structure, like

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document
{
    private Integer id;
    private String content;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each XML element (not attribute) in JAXB is a Java class.
And attribute can be a property.
So you have to have something like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document
{
   @XmlElement(name = "field")
   private List<Field> field = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@XmlType()
public class Field
{
   @XmlAttribute(name="name", required="true")
   private String name;

   @XmlValue
   private Object value;

}
```

Actually **`private Object value;`** translates to `XML anyType` so you will be able to set it to `Integer` for `id`, `String` for `content` etc.

BTW your current `Document` class marshalls to XML as

```
<Document>
      <id></id>
      <content></content>
      <title></title>
      <author></author>
      <b></b>
<Document>
```